# How To Fix Issue Of Unity Remote 5 not Working

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unity-remote

I tried everything but I am not abled to test my game on my mobile device but problems are coming 1.In resolution options I set it to Android Remote and in that always Android Remote is not connected is shown 2.there is warning coming that Set-up Android SDK Path to make Android Remote work

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you can see the smartphone files in the PC explorer.
2. Enable debugging in the developer menu on your smartphone.
3. First connect your smartphone to PC, then launch the Unity Remote app, then launch Unity and check.